# XHR request response stream works in IE but not Edge

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

If you have a minute, I am making an XHR request against a Tomcat servlet which returns an XML stream. I have been looking at the scale of converting from ActiveX MSXML to XHR. I incorporated promises as ActiveX was synch while XHR is async. The return XML is voluminous but the XHR request has no problem in IE 11. Edge seems to hang and stops execution. Nothing happens. Another "smaller" XHR request, grabbing the XSL, is fine. The Tomcat log says it handles the request from Edge and sends the response, no problem. Anyway, the code is pretty straightforward. Thank you very much.

```
 xmldoc =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {           
            xmldoc.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==  200) {
               
                   alert(xmldoc.responseText);
                   resolve(xmldoc);
                } 
            };
            xmldoc.open("GET", url, true);
            xmldoc.send();     
        }, 200);
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use fetch or axios and then use babel/ polyfills for older browsers. Do know that the new Edge has a IE compatibility mode

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yeah, I haven't been able to check IE mode as I need third party desktop support to set the policy. That's why I was kind of looking at the scope of converting all this. It's strange that the older browser, IE 11, has no issues with this request while Edge just seems to hang/stop. Have you done IE mode? I am worried about two things...1) IE Internet Options.- "Enable ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" Is that enabled by default in IE mode since there are no Internet Options for the Edge window? and 2) MSXML support. Is the IE 11 vers included with IE mode? thnx

Comment: If you open the url directly in edge does it load?

Comment: Hold the phone...ok...entering the url directly...both IE and Edge display the raw XML...however...in IE, it has this heading...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>...while in Edge, it says..."This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." and no <?xml version...> tag. I wouldn't think that would be a problem unless Edge is trying to do something with it.

Comment: Hello. After figuring out how to debug in Edge, this turned out to be CORS filter error from Tomcat. I set the filter in web.xml, with a specific cors.allowed.origins. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out how to debug in Edge, this turned out to be CORS filter error from Tomcat. I set the filter in web.xml, with a specific cors.allowed.origins. tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter